# Making partitions and running OSs

Tags: linux, operating-system, usb, partition

So I happen to have a pretty huge USB Thumb Drive *(Sandisk 128GB)*, and I don't make much use of it. I was wondering if I could make partitions to it and run a portable operating system on it. Don't misunderstand me here, I know how to flash OSs on a USB. But I was wondering, if I could flash it on a separate partition. Suppose I want **100GB for storing normal files**. And I make a partition in it for 100GB. The rest **14GB, I want to run a Linux distro** on. Is it possible to just flash it on that 14GB partition? If yes, what are the challenges I'll be facing?

Comment: I've never tried it. But, something I can think of being closely to this is `raspberry pi`..

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.